# Changing the div height dynamically based on the content and setting a vertical scroll bar when it overflows.

Tags: html, css, height, overflow

I have a `div` which its height is fixed. Inside that `div` there are two `divs` where heights are dynamically changing because of the content inside `divs`.

```
<div id="panel">
    <div id="layerTree">

    </div>

    <div id="features">
        <div id="accordion_equip"></div>
        <div id="accordion_equip"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside `features div` there are two `divs` that has accordion. Whenever when we click on that accordion because of the data in accordion `features div` should have a vertical scroll bar.

**But vertical scroll bar appears when we set a fixed height for the `features div`. But I can't set a fixed height because the `layerTree div` height also changing based on the content inside.**

So, how to fix this issue?

CSS :

```
#panel {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}

#features {
    height: 365px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Unfortunately I can't attach any images of current UI because of the security restrictions.

Comment: Do the said *security restrictions* also forbid you to create a [mcve] of your problem? Replace the passwords and bank accounts with dummy data, if you have to...

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu working on it

Comment: can i expect any fiddle or image wht you are asking for? so that i can fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using JS.

```
            fixHeight = function() {
                var p = $('#layerTree').outerHeight();
                var featureHeight = 555 - p;
                $("#features").css("height", featureHeight);
            };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `min-height` for this content. So, When content height is not same with `min-height` it's take `height` automatic according to your content height.

```
#features {
    min-height: 365px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

If, You want show the vertical scroll bar then You can set below css rules.

```
#features {
    max-height: 365px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't show the vertical scroll bar as well when I click on the accordion.

Comment: If You want show vertical bar. You can set  max-height: 365px; and overflow-y: scrol;

Answer (score 0):

update css

```
#features {
    min-height: 365px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it does not a display a vertical scroll bar when max-height is 100%.

Comment: It works for the defined width. But whenever layerTree content is changing, still height of features div is 365px. :(